# How to quickly remove current page from my bookmarks in Safari

Tags: macos, shortcuts, safari, productivity

I've been using both Safari and Chrome a lot, and while using Chrome, if I opened a page that I've already bookmarked and I want to un-bookmark it, just need to press Command+D and click the remove button. But I have no idea if I could do the same in Safari.

Comment: What happened when you tried it in Safari?

Comment: @MichaelFrank In Safari, I also can use Command+D to save page as bookmark, the dialog pops out is quite the same as in Chrome, but doesn't have a remove button like Chrome or Firefox do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no such Hotkey command for such a task

Comment: @Sickest Yeah, I'm afraid so.